# "If only 10 years ago..." -- punctuation

Tags: punctuation

I want to write this:

- If only 10 years ago I would have thought the way I do today.

How should I punctuate this? I am not sure where commas go. I haven't tried much yet.

Comment: Are you trying to write all of that, or are some of those sentences giving us information. I mean, what sentence or sentences exactly are you trying to write? This sentence alone: *If only 10 years ago I would have thought the way I do today* or everything after your first clause?

Comment: **A**  *Will/would* is used in a condition clause (protasis) only if 1)It has a volitive sense (= 'be willing to') or 2)it accepts as fact a future event predicted earlier in the discourse (e.g., "If as you say the auditors will be here tomorrow, we should spend the afternoon getting the books  up to date"). Your clause should read*... I had thought ...*  **B** Your example is not a sentence, only a condition clause. It may be preceded by a comma if the missing consequence clause comes before it, or followed by a comma before a following consequence clause. It requires no internal comma.

Comment: You **did** write this. I've read it.

Comment: If only 10 years ago I **had** thought the way I do today."  but this would be clearer thus:  "If only I had thought 10 years ago the way I do today."  This eliminates the ambiguity as to whether "only" applies to "years", or "if only" applies to "I had".

Comment: @StoneyB If only  StoneyB would answer even more questions! If only it would stop raining. If only it would .... ! Isn't it more the case that we just don't use *would* with the first person in this type of construction? What d'you think?

Comment: @Araucaria Certainly in the StoneyB piece, and I think in the rain piece too,  that's a volitive *will*. It may seem a little odd to attribute volition to a dummy subject, but consider *It **will** keep raining when I want to play golf.* The boundary between volitive and habitual *will* is fuzzy. But I think it's pretty clearly not a futurive will.

Comment: Seriously people, can we stop editing the question beyond what the user has asked?

Answer (score 1):

Commas are only required if the boundaries between clauses/phrases would be unclear without them.

Conditionals often have multiple clauses, but this sentence is leaving out the explicit "then" part of the conditional for dramatic effect.  So there isn't really a boundary to worry about.

> If only 10 years ago I would have thought the way I do today.

The word order really makes this a single, complete clause.  Adding any commas will confuse a reader.  So, no commas.

Answer (score 0):

There are no commas required, the sentence is punctuated correctly as is. However, it is also not a complete sentence. To make a complete sentence, you also need a clause that says *what would have happened* "if only 10 years ago I would have thought the way I do today."

For example, "If only 10 years ago I would have thought the way I do today, I would have traveled the world more."